# How to process a string in NSIS?

Tags: string, substring, nsis, strcpy

I have a string from the parameters that has a installation path using this code:

```
${GetParameters} $R0
${if} $R0 != ""
    StrCpy $R1 $R0 "" 3
    StrCpy $INSTDIR $R1 -1          
${endif}
```

the $INSTDIR contains a path like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Applicatoin
```

I want to get **"My Application"** out of it and save it in a variable. I know that I should check the characters backwards until i reach the **backslash ( \ )** but I do not know how to implement it in NSIS syntax.

How can I get **"My Application"** from the folder path using NSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most string operations can be coded with just `StrCpy`, `StrCmp` and `StrLen`.

A basic version that only checks `\` and not `/` already exists:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
StrCpy $0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Application"
${GetFileName} $0 $1
DetailPrint $1
```